# how do you delete all files NOT a flag in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to delete all items NOT .aspx, but i wasn't sure how to do it.  Right now i was just going through everything with

```
del /F *.html
del /F *.csproj
del /F *.ico
```

etc.

Is there a simpler command to just say:  DELETE EVERYTHING in DIRECTORY NOT a FOLDER OR has an extension of .aspx

I cant seem to find a solution on the Internet which matches my question.  I didn't know if DEL accepted Regex to be like `/^.*(^\.aspx)$` or something

bash file says:

```
chdir C:\Users\william.francis\Desktop\Deploy\tmp
for /f "delims=ÿ" %a in ('dir /b /a-d ^| find /v ".aspx"') do del /s /q /f %a
chdir ..
```

**Edit:** would like a reason as to the downvotes so i could fix it.  I find this question to be valid enough to not get penalized.  *shrug*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
for /f "delims=ÿ" %a in ('dir /b /ad ^| find /v ".aspx"') do rd /s /q %a
for /f "delims=ÿ" %a in ('dir /b /a-d ^| find /v ".aspx"') do del /s /q /f %a
```

Please run it on a test directory first.

Another form:

```
for /f "delims=ÿ" %a in ('dir /b /a-d') do if not "%~xa"==".aspx" del /q %a
```

As a batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=ÿ" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ^| find /v ".aspx"') do del /s /q /f %%a
```

Or

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=ÿ" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do if not "%%~xa"==".aspx" del /q %%a
```

Save it to a file like `file.bat`, or `file.cmd` then run `x:\path\to\file.bat` or `x:\path\to\file.cmd`.

Comment: i do not think that the first one would resolve it as that is removing directories.  I dont need to do that, nor search those directories... just CUR_DIR.  With that said, the second statement you have seems to have done the trick.  there are 5 files which shouldve been deleted.  Those 5 are found and it returned:

Deleted file - foo/bar.config, etc.

Comment: when putting it in a bash script though, it does not seem to like that.  I.E.  chdir foo [your command] chdir ..

Comment: @Fallenreaper It's a cmd.exe command. You can compile those on a file called a batch file. Batch files are different from bash or shell scripts.

Comment: ohhhh. ok, i created a bash script (i think) i guess i need to turn my script into a file?

Comment: How would i go about taking this batch file i created and then successfully running it?  Is there something special i should be doing?

Comment: running the newly created bat file, it errors saying:  a was unexpected at this time.   though i copied your command correctly.

Comment: Place the file on a directory different from your target directory like your home directory or somewhere accessible with %PATH% like `C:\windows\system32`. When running it you can just have the filename e.g. `file` or the whole name `file.bat`. If it's not in %PATH%, you should specify the complete path.

Comment: @Fallenreaper In batch files, arguments of `for` should have double `%%`'s. I forgot to update the first one. Please try again.